# Java mismatching(??) references between associated classes

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I'm sure this should be easy but I've been stucked for hours without understanding what's really happening in this code:

```
private void loadUnits() {
        units = new ArrayList<Unit>(); //units is a class global variable
        families = new ArrayList<Family>(); //families is a class global variable
        Statement st;
        Statement stFields;
        ResultSet rs;
        ResultSet rsFields;
        try {
            //Load units info
            st = cnnSrc.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = st.executeQuery(Queries.qUnits);
            while (rs.next()) {
                units.add(new Unit(rs));
            }//END_WHILE
            ConnectionProvider.close(rs, st);

            //First load fields info
            stFields = cnnSrc.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rsFields = stFields.executeQuery(Queries.qFields);

            //Now load the Family information and create their instances
            st = cnnSrc.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = st.executeQuery(Queries.qFamily);
            while (rs.next()) {
                families.add(new Family(rs, rsFields, units));
                this.debugGlobalParams();
            }//END_WHILE
            ConnectionProvider.close(rsFields, stFields);
            ConnectionProvider.close(rs, st);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }//END_TRYCATCH
    }//END_METHOD

public void debugGlobalParams() {
        int n = units.size();
        int nu = 0;
        String unitNames = "";
        LOGGER.debug("Debugging " + n + " Units");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            LOGGER.debug(units.get(i).getParkUnitTitleAersa());
        }

        n = families.size();
        LOGGER.debug("Debugging " + n + " Families");
        Family f;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            f = families.get(i);
            LOGGER.debug("FamilyId = " + f.getFamilyId() + "; FamilyTitle = " + f.getFamilyTitle() + "; Tabla = " + f.getTabla());
            nu = f.getUnits().size();
            for (int j = 0; j < nu; j++) {
                unitNames = unitNames + f.getUnits().get(j).getParkUnitTitleAersa() + ",";
            }
            LOGGER.debug("Units included => " + unitNames);
        }
    }//END_METHOD
```

This method is called once to get from DB my simple domain model, which should contain some Family descriptions and Unit descriptions as well. Each Unit should belong to one, and only one Family, and that association is done during the second `while` where I'm creating a new Family instance. The Unit constructor method is trivial, but for you to know the most relevant code on the Family constructor:

```
public Family(ResultSet rs, ResultSet rsFields, ArrayList<Unit> uns) {
        try {
//Some local variables assignment...
            units = new ArrayList<Unit>();

            int n = uns.size();
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                if(uns.get(i).getFamilyId() == this.FamilyId){
                    this.units.add(uns.get(i));
                }
            }//END_FOR
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }//END_TRYCATCH
    }//END_METHOD
```

Now, the problem is that the association between Family and their proper units is not done properly and when I call `this.debugGlobalParams()` I find that each Family is not only getting their units but also the previous family's units.
For example, if I have as families f1, f2 and f3 and each of them has three units u11, u12, u13, u21, u22, u23, u31, u32, u33 (where the first number indicates the family it should be associated with), I should be getting:

```
f1 -> u11, u12, u13
f2 -> u21, u22, u23
f3 -> u31, u32, u33
```

But instead I get this:

```
f1 -> u11, u12, u13
f2 -> u11, u12, u13, u21, u22, u23
f3 -> u11, u12, u13, u21, u22, u23, u31, u32, u33
```

I'm sure the problem is with the references but I don't understand why.... Anybody some ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: May you show also the queries, above all the Queries.qUnits

Comment: I think it's not relevant.......the only thing I believe it matters regarding queries and/or tables is that each Unit row has a FamilyId that a matches a single row in Family table. That's why you'll find `uns.get(i).getFamilyId() == this.FamilyId` in the Family constructor method.

Comment: I saw the if, but it seems that it doesn't work...now your vode seems to be OK so I was asking for the query

Comment: @Hauri Can you show us the constructor of Family? and the declaration of the fields units and FamilyId. It looks like `units` is static.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's declared the following way: `private int FamilyId;` and `private ArrayList<Unit> units;` both as class Family variables.

Comment: @Hauri How do you assign the FamilyId? i can't see it in the code

Comment: And basically you should split database code and data object. There is no reason that the class `Family` should have a dependency on `ResultSet`

Comment: And show us the `debugGlobalParams()` method, this code also be a bug in this method

Comment: Hi @Absurd-Mind , I've updated my question to include the `debugGlobalParams()` method. The `FamilyId` is assigned from ResultSet input param. Yes, I know I should not be creating this kind of dependencies, but was the easier way to avoid extra queries to DB. I'm already changing the approach to avoid this problem but I would still like to know what was happening in the code.... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is your debug display code. You put all unit names from one family into unitNames, but do not reset this String. Quick hack would be to reset the String:

```
    n = families.size();
    LOGGER.debug("Debugging " + n + " Families");
    Family f;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unitNames = "";   // <----------- ADD THIS LINE
        f = families.get(i);
        LOGGER.debug("FamilyId = " + f.getFamilyId() + "; FamilyTitle = " + f.getFamilyTitle() + "; Tabla = " + f.getTabla());
        nu = f.getUnits().size();
        for (int j = 0; j < nu; j++) {
            unitNames = unitNames + f.getUnits().get(j).getParkUnitTitleAersa() + ",";
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Units included => " + unitNames);
    }
```

A better solution would be to use iterators or Iterables, and declare the variable inside the loop:

```
for (Family f : families) {
      LOGGER.debug("FamilyId = " + f.getFamilyId() + "; FamilyTitle = " + f.getFamilyTitle() + "; Tabla = " + f.getTabla());

    String unitNames = "";
    for (Unit unit : f.getUnits() {
        unitNames = unitNames + unit.getParkUnitTitleAersa() + ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. I feel quite stupid right now......considering the time I've spent on this. Thanks again!